# Can't upsert JSON with mongoimport

Tags: json, mongodb, upsert, mongoimport

I want to use JSON to batch upsert to a mongo collection.

```
    $ mongoexport -d myDB -c myCollection
    connected to: 127.0.0.1
    { "_id" : "john", "age" : 27 }
```

But using the syntax I would in the mongo shell yields:

```
    0$ echo '{_id:"john", {$set:{gender:"male"}}' | mongoimport --upsert --upsertFields _id -d myDB -c myCollection
    connected to: 127.0.0.1
    Fri Jul 27 15:01:32 Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near: , {$set:{g
    0x581a52 0x528554 0xa9f2e3 0xaa1593 0xa980cd 0xa9c062 0x3e7ca1ec5d 0x4fe239
    ...
    /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x3e7ca1ec5d]  mongoimport(__gxx_personality_v0+0x3c9) [0x4fe239]
    exception:Failure parsing JSON string near: , {$set:{g

    imported 0 objects
    encountered 1 error
```

When I try it without the curly brackets, it yields no error but doesn't change the table:

```
    0$ echo '{_id:"john", $set:{gender:"male"}}' | mongoimport --upsert --upsertFields _id -d myDB -c myCollection
    connected to: 127.0.0.1
    imported 1 objects
    0$ mongoexport -d myDB -c myCollection
    connected to: 127.0.0.1
    { "_id" : "john", "age" : 27 }
    exported 1 records
```

I've searched everywhere but can't find an example using JSON. Please help!

Comment: Where is the data coming from? You are probably better off writing a script in any language you want (php/python/perl/etc) and doing the operations directly from there (using the language driver).

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, MongoImport doesn't evaluate commands.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Andre's answer.

Mongoimport takes a single file that contains 1 JSON/CSV/TSV string per line and inserts it. You can import from standard out but not as a command as above. You can use mongoimport to perform an upsert as per [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-Example%3aImportingwith%7B%7Bupsert%7D%7D).

You can run mongoimport with the [stoponError option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport--stopOnError), which will force mongoimport to stop when it encounters an error.

Here's the complete [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongoimport/) for mongoimport and, as a FYI, mongoimport doesn't reliably preserve all rich BSON data types.

Comment: I tried basing it on that command but can't see how to do it with JSON, rather than CSV?

Answer (score 1):

Mongoimport does not take modifiers such as your $set. You will need to use the mongo --eval command to update.

```
mongo myDB --eval 'db.myCollection.update({_id: "john"}, {$set:{gender:"male"}}, upsert=true)'
```

Hope this helps.